# Apache2 Error Log [info] [client] Request body read timeout

Tags: php, ajax, apache, curl, runtime-error

I have a .ajax request that sends a url to a php page. The php page uses a CURL request to scrape the content off the website and looks for a backlink to our page.

Heres the CRUL call

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1", // Pretend were FireFox
CURLOPT_URL => $row['page_href'], // Backlink
CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE, // don't return headers
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, // return web page
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => FALSE, // dont follow redirects
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $connectionTimeout, // seconds to wait while trying to connect
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $curlTimeout, // seconds for everything to complete
CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip,deflate'));

$htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$response = $info['http_code'];
curl_close($ch);
```

I then look for the backlink and return the results.

Every time this ajax call completes the Apache 2 error log prints:

```
[Mon Jan 21 16:48:51 2013] [info] [client IP.ADDRESS] Request body read timeout
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I dont know for 100% that it is the curl call thats the issue here. I just know that when the JQuery .ajax() completes (or at some point in the loop because it happens fast) I get another line in the error log.

**UPDATE:**

Ive seen this error pop up now too. It happens seemingly at random but not very often.

```
[info] [client IP.ADD] (32)Broken pipe: core_output_filter: writing data to the network
```

Comment: Have you tried running the php script in command line to see if it works as expected?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm trying to look up how to do that but I dont see how to send parameters to my script.

Comment: Either run the php script directly from browser (instead of using ajax, just type it in the URL box) or if you have command line access go to the directory where the script is located and type "php scriptname.php"

Comment: Ill just hard code some fake data.

Comment: Ok I ran it from command line and it does exactly what its supposed to do. It grabs the URL, curls the page, looks for a link back to my site, and returns an associative array of the back-link text etc. The ajax call works fine, I get the results I want. But why is this [info] line showing up repeatedly?

Comment: could be a firewall (or something like suhosin/selinux) that's preventing your webserver from opening outgoing http requests. commandline would most likely NOT be bound by a such a restriction.

Comment: How about when you run it from browser?

Comment: Same thing. It runs just as expected.

Comment: Thought: are you making this request to your own server? Are you using sessions? Remember that php's default file session handler LOCKS the session file while a request is in flight, so if you're requesting something of yourself, you'll get a deadlock.

Comment: Hello Marc, Yes I am using sessions and the curl call is to a random url out in the world (so not my server). I grab the $_SESSION variable before I make the curl call and then stick info from the curl call into the return array.

Comment: Marc, so if I have an .ajax request from index.php that goes to check.php. While that ajax request is alive I cannot use $_SESSION on index.php? Is that what you mean? Because there are 6 ajax calls to check.php going at a time. When one completes another is sent until I process a few thousand URL's. So the next call to check.php is accessing the server variable. For the record Im not getting any php errors though.

Comment: Hi again Marc, I just got another error PHP Notice:  session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php5) failed: Permission denied (13) in /path/to/update.php on line 4, referer: http://localhost/ - I think this was what you were referring too. Its another page hit by ajax every so often to update the status bar of the page.